# connection to database performance

Tags: php, performance

I'm interested in efficiency of connection to database, should I keep reconnecting to database in every if condition like this:

```
if(a > b)
{
    connect to database(mysqli_connect(...,....))
    do some stuff
    close connection to database
}
if(c == d)
{
    connect to database(mysqli_connect(...,....))
    do some stuff
    close connection to database
}
```

Or efficiency would be better in this way:

```
connect to database(mysqli_connect(...,....))
if(a > b)
{
    do some stuff
}
if(c == d)
{
    do some stuff
}
close connection to database
```

Comment: logic would suggest b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only open the connection 1 time and preferably only when needed.

```
$connection = null;

function connect()
{
    if(is_null($connection)) {
        $connection = (mysqli_connect(...,....))
    }
    return $connection;
}

if(a > b)
{
    connect();    
    do some stuff

}
if(c == d)
{
    connect();
    do some stuff
}

if($connection)
    close connection to database
```